# Java/XML request problem

Tags: java, xml, resultset

First time poster here. The problem I am facing is in Java and XML. The problem I am faced with is, a user will send a VerifyAccount XML request to our systems and depending on what information was sent, our system will verify the account, send a unregistered user error or a invalid account error. 
I have done some work on the code, I added an element into the XML schema and it worked only if in the request the newly created element was parsed in the xml. The problem is I don't want to pass that element in the XML requests, but if I exclude the element the code does not work properly.

The Java function is:

```
    private String checkPersonID(String[] loginDetails, String serviceName, Connection conn, Element service) throws SQLException, JspException
    {
        assert loginDetails != null : "You need to set loginDetails before calling checkPersonID()";
        assert serviceName  != null : "You need to set serviceName before calling checkPersonID()";

        CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall( "{call jspCheckPersonID (?)}" )

        try
        {
            stmt.setString(1, loginDetails[INDEX_USERNAME] );
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            // Make sure this person is a valid user - if so return his personID, otherwise throw appropriate Exception
            if (serviceName.equals ("AccountVerify") && service.getChild("ServiceDetail").getChild("detailedErrorMesage").getText().equals ("true") && !rs.next())
            {
                throw new JspException( JspException.UNREGISTERED_ACCOUNT );
            }           
            else if ( rs.getRow() != 1 || !rs.getString("Password").trim().equalsIgnoreCase( loginDetails[INDEX_PASSWORD] ))
            {
                throw new JspException( JspException.INVALID_ACCOUNT );
            }

// code ommitted
```

The newly added element in the XML is detailedErrorMessage.

The XML request should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="--" Version="1.0">
    <Identification>
        <UserID>your.address@your.company</UserID>
        <Password>password</Password>
    </Identification>
    <Service>
        <ServiceName>AccountVerify</ServiceName>

        <ServiceDetail/>
    </Service>
</Request>
```

That is the request, if the detailedErrorMesage element is added into this request the function works as intended. What am I doing wrong in this code? I have been thinking about it for a couple of days and it's doing my head in!

Any help will be very much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you just need to mark the element as optional in the schema. Set minOccurs to 0 and maxOccurs to 1 to create an optional element.

EDIT: After rereading, it seems that if you don't have a detailedErrorMessage, your if block will throw a NullPointerException. When you chain together a bunch of method calls like that where any of them could be null, you are playing with fire. Validate that each child exists before you check the value.

Comment: Currently minOccurs is set as 0 and maxOccurs is not set. I believe it should set to 1 as default?